# Laravel select only categories wherein product ids

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hi i have a categories and products table with one to many relation. I want to select categories with products which are in product_ids(which it will get from other query). I tried

```
$categories = Category::with(['products' => function ($query) use($product_ids) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $product_ids);
    }])
    ->get();
```

the above query will select all the categories even if the product not in product_ids ( empty array if not in produc_id) but i just want to select those categories which has the products in the product_ids.please help

Answer (score 0):

I just Solved it by adding whereHas

```
$categories = Category::with(['products' => function ($query) use($product_ids) {
      $query->whereIn('id', $product_ids);
    }])
->whereHas('products', function ($q) use($product_ids) {
      $q->whereIn('id', $product_ids);
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `whereHas`

```
$categories = Category::whereHas('products', function ($query) use($product_ids) {
    $query->whereIn('id', $product_ids);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: yes but using only wherehas will give all the products of that category even if not in product_ids so to filter that i used 'with' also

Comment: did you read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)? It will retrieve all categories that have products from products_id list.